# RabbitMQ Consumer using WPF

Tags: wpf, rabbitmq

I was wondering if there are any RabbitMQ examples where I can run a consumer and display the messages on the UI in WPF. I see many different approaches on-line and I am able to get it working using a background worker. Is using asynch/ wait a better approach, or TPL? I'm using the lastest version of RabbitMQ. I looking for a simple WPF example to get started.